# operation not permitted error while copyinf font file to localdisk c

Tags: permissions

trying to copy the font file in C:/Windows/Fonts/ but it gives permitting error any solution on how to run this script as admin

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe right-click on cmd or powershell (which ever terminal program you are using) and run it as Administrator. Then try running your script. It cannot be that easy though, perhaps I am not understanding you.